# how can I sort out a missing required positional argument

Tags: python, pygame

In my case this is the error I get when I run the code:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Screen'
```

Now usually this is easily fixable but for some weird reason I can't seem to solve the problem. I use to have a perfectly fine piece of code but now that I started messing around with it, my code is now riddled with errors. I would go back to my old code but once I sort out the errors this new code will by far be a lot better than the old one. Hey like they say, "You got to take everything one step at a time".

The code (sorry for giving such large code but I don't know whether you may need the full code or not in my case):

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
objs = []
MAIN_BUTTON = 1


class Pane():

    def __init__(self, textToDisplay, coordinates, screen):
        self.textToDisplay = textToDisplay
        self.coordinates = coordinates
        self.screen = screen

    def drawPane(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.font.render(textToDisplay, True, (black)), (250, 115))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (black), self.coordinates, 2)
        pygame.display.update()


class Screen():

    #constants/array(?) outlining the x,y boundaries of each of x10 panes

    #Remember to change co-ordinate values
    #number of panes
    NoOfPanes = 0
    Panes = []

    def __init__(self, Screen):
        pygame.init()
        pygame.display.set_caption('Box Test')

        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 25)
        Screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,600), 0, 32)
        self.screen = Screen #I'm guessing the error of my code is somewhere around here, however I thought that I had overcome the situation. Evidently I haven't "sigh"!
        self.screen.fill((white))

        pygame.display.update()

    def addPane(self, textToDisplay):
        #right now it is displaying them all change so that it checks how many
        #panes are on through (numberOfPanes = 0) 10 is limit display no more
        #than ten.
        paneLocs = [(175, 75, 200, 100), 
                    (0, 0, 200, 100), 
                    (600, 400, 200, 100), 
                    (175, 75, 200, 100), 
                    (175, 75, 200, 100), 
                    (175, 75, 200, 100), 
                    (175, 75, 200, 100), 
                    (175, 75, 200, 100), 
                    (175, 75, 200, 100), 
                    (175, 75, 200, 100)
                    ]

        if self.NoOfPanes > 10:
            print("Limit Reached")            
        else:
            #self.Panes[self.NoOfPanes] = Pane(textToDisplay, paneLocs[self.NoOfPanes])
            #self.Panes[self.NoOfPanes].drawPane()

            myPane = Pane(textToDisplay, paneLocs[self.NoOfPanes])
            myPane.drawPane()

            self.NoOfPanes = self.NoOfPanes + 1
            pygame.display.update()


    def mousePosition(self):
        global clickPos
        global releasePos
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == MAIN_BUTTON:
                self.Pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                return MAIN_BUTTON
            else:
                return False


if __name__ == '__main__':

    myScreen = Screen()
    myScreen.addPane("1")
    myScreen.addPane("2")
    myScreen.addPane("3")
    myScreen.addPane("4")

    while True:
        ev = pygame.event.get()
        for event in ev:
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                posx,posy = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                if (posx >= 175 and posx <= 375) and (posy >= 75 and posy <= 175):
                    print("BOB") #Printing bob was for test purposes.

        for event in pygame.event.get():        
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit(); sys.exit();
```

Thank-you in advance for your time and effort.

Comment: Do you use a VCS yet? (e.g. Git or Mercurial. Bazaar would also be passable)

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback? It's hard to figure out where the exception is coming from with just the last piece of it. The rest of the traceback should tell you exactly what line is causing the problem.

Comment: Your event loop is split into two loops. One can eat the events the other is expecting. It should be one for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your constructor for the `Screen` class has a rogue parameter:

```
def __init__(self, Screen): <-- the 'Screen' here is causing the issue.
```

That's what your error message seems to be saying. Remove the 'Screen' param as otherwise Python thinks that is a positional (named) parameter.

As as aside: I'd also recommend reading through the Python style guide (Google for `PEP-8`). You appear to use casing reserved for classes for variables and does make the code less readable for anyone that's written Python for any reasonable length of time.

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply however I have removed Screen from within the parameter however I still get this error message:
<Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Burak\Desktop\boxtrial.py", line 87, in <module>
    myScreen.addPane("1")
  File "C:\Users\Burak\Desktop\boxtrial.py", line 66, in addPane
    myPane = Pane(textToDisplay, paneLocs[self.NoOfPanes])
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'screen'>

Comment: @PythonNovice: Your Pane constructor expects a third argument named 'screen'. So: `myPane = Pane(textToDisplay, paneLocs[self.NoOfPanes])` should be `myPane = Pane(textToDisplay, paneLocs[self.NoOfPanes], screen)` where `screen` is presumably of type `Screen` which means you can say: `myPane = Pane(textToDisplay, paneLocs[self.NoOfPanes], Screen())` whereby you instantiate one in the call to the Pane constructor itself.